# Block Control+Alt+Delete

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing an Online Quiz project in C#. The test client is a Windows Desktop Application running on Windows XP. I need to block the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> key combination to prevent students from minimizing/closing the application.

Using PInvoke is okay for me.

I know this is definitely possible because I have seen three applications doing this. They are all proprietary, so I have no way of knowing how it was done.

Comment: Could you tell us which proprietary applications can do this?

Comment: What does your proprietary application when the user does a Ctrl+Shift+Esc or a right clic on the Task Bar > Task Manager ?

Comment: I've seen these in places like Lowes and McDonalds: Little employment signup kiosks that won't let you Ctrl-Alt-Delete out to the underlying windows. But you ask: how do i know it's windows if i can't get out? i didn't say *i can't get out*, i said *you cant use ctrl-alt-delete to get out*! (Hint: there's more than one way to get to the desktop)

Comment: Is disabling ctrl-alt-del to stop users from surfing the web to find the answers / browsing the file system to modify the data files? If so, you need to consider a lot more than just disabling ctrl-alt-del. There's Win-D for starters. Win-E. Win-U is a pain too (the utility manager). Then there's the common dialog for save/load/open.

Comment: @Simon H : Those were the assessment applications of some companies which I had to use during their interview process. It didn't even have a name (except the name of the company).

Comment: @RCIX, Skizz : I managed to disable all other keys - Win+E,Win+D, Shift+Esc, Alt+Tab etc. I'm simply not able to block Control+Alt+Del. I'm not using the common dialog control. It loads the quiz from a web service.

Comment: If you application is running on your students' own machines, you should give up hope of preventing them from killing it.  If nothing else, they can physically turn off their laptop, or use an external program on a timer or something.  Or be using a tool like winsplitrevolution, which sends commands to applications for resizing and the like.

Comment: Restricting that much control on a machine you don't own just does not feel right. I mean, what kind of quiz is so important that the only way to recover your computer, in case the application crashes, is to reboot it (or even send it to maintenance) ?

Comment: @RaphaelSP: The quiz scores will count to their final grades so it's pretty important that it's not too easy to cheat. n basically it's a simple application. Hoping it wouldn't crash :) It hasn't so far while testing.

Comment: @Brian: They are free to quit anytime by submitting the answers or they could turn it off. They only should not be able to browse the internet/local system for answers.

Comment: @evans: and what will you do if they own two computers ?
What will you do if they have paper books ? Do you want your application to prevent them from reading paper ?

It's a REALLY BAD idea to prevent them from doing anything on their PERSONAL computers. They own it, they rules it. I will hate anybody who forces me to install an application trying to take over control of my computer, you ask us how to build a malware.

Comment: Reading these comments, it appears the whole idea of stopping Ctrl-Atl-Del is futile. You can't stop someone doing the test from a remote location from: a) running in a VM, b) using books, c) having more than one PC, d) using linux and Mono.

Comment: You said in the comments that you can "disable" the task manager(by killing every time it gets started). Why is the ability to open Windows Security a problem if they can't start task manager from there?

Comment: An unsupervised test is an unsupervized test.  You don't even know that it's the actual student on the computer, not to mention other resources and other computers.  Not to mention that fiddling with system internals like that is likely to mess up somebody's computer.  Got liability insurance for that?  This is a Bad Idea.

Comment: It will NOT be an unsupervised test. The teacher will be in the classroom. The students will be using laptops to take the test in the classroom. So, using other computers etc is not possible. I just need to prevent students from Minimizing the application, finding the answers, and then maximizing it again when the teacher comes near their desk.

Comment: If your application loses focus, then he is probably cheating, so the supervisor should be notified. That seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Windows XP, the correct way to do this is to create your own Graphical Identification and Authentication Dynamic Link Library, or gina.dll for short. [Here's an MSDN article about it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742447.aspx). This DLL exports a set of functions that interact with the Winlogon process and provides the user interface to logon requests - the Secure Action Sequence event. The main logon request is the ctrl-alt-delete response. The standard gina.dll invokes the logon screen or the task manager/logoff dialog. It's not too difficult to create your own gina but it does require C/C++ coding and not C# and it is quite easy to make the system fail to boot. This does not stop people from pressing F8 at boot up and selecting the Safe Boot option, which won't load the custom gina.dll.

EDIT: I should also say that you don't need to implement all the functions the gina is required to implement, you can dynamically load the previous gina.dll and pass all the calls you're not interested in to the old gina.dll.

EDIT 2: This **does not work** with Vista/Win7 as they changed the architecture of the logon process. It is still possible to disable ctrl-alt-delete in Vista/Win7 but it requires a different mechanism - there are MSDN articles about it somewhere.

EDIT 3: [Here's a ZIP file containing the source code to make a gina.dll](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/dave.faller/download/gina.zip) It was built using DevStudio 2005. The file GinaInterface.cpp details the steps needed to install the new gina.dll library. This will disable the "Welcome" screen and replace it with the 'press crtl-alt-del' to login dialog. As it stands, there is no difference between this and a standard gina.dll, all the gina related calls are passed through to the original gina.dll file (called msgina.dll in the Windows\System32 folder). To disable the ctrl-alt-del key press, update the function WlxLoggedOnSAS in GinaInterface.cpp. To stop ctrl-alt-del whilst your application is running, you could create a named mutex (CreateMutex) and test for its presence in the gina.dll, stopping ctrl-alt-del if the mutex exists.

Comment: I don't want to actually replace any dll - basically,I don't want to make any permanent changes - even the worst of crashes should be fixed by a restart.

Comment: I read the article, but it kinda goes over my head. Could you provide some more help on that? A link to a working sample perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: A working sample? That's not a quick thing to do! I do have the source to a gina.dll replacement to hand, but it's too large to post directly here and it needs a bit of editing to strip it down to what you need. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The ZIP file link is broken :-(

Comment: @ThomasWeller: This was 12 years ago! I've moved several times and upgraded my web hosting a couple of times too. I still have some of the original code but I've no idea if it's the same as the code I posted, I may have stripped out application specific code to make a bare bones implementation so I'm not going to post what I have just to be safe (copyright lawyers are evil!). Also, it was for WinXP and won't work at all on Win7 or newer.

Answer (score 25):

I found a very ugly way of doing this (which works well).
If I **open taskmgr.exe exclusively**, then **nothing happens** when the user presses Ctrl+Alt+Del.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "taskmgr.exe"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

What I like the most about this solution that it has no permanent effects. For example if the application gets killed, then Ctrl+Alt+Del will just work again.

**Drawback:** One must have the Welcome screen enabled or Windows Security will popup instead of Windows trying to open taskmgr and silently failing. (→ It also won't work if the machine is in a domain, because being in a domain disables the Welcome screen.)

*(Of course this won't work on Vista or W7.)*

Comment: Dude...I'm amazed and shocked of that solution at the same time. ;) Nice one.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might also want to block the functionality of Ctrl+Shift+Esc.

Comment: It's a bit crazy that this works, but I guess TaskMgr is just a regular .exe.

Answer (score 12):

As other people have mentioned it's very hard to block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>, as it's a fundamental part of Windows security.

However you can block what can be done after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> has been pushed by adding the  following registry keys.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**

- DisableTaskMgr
- DisableChangePassword
- DisableLockWorkstation

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer**

- NoLogoff

If you do this then when you push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> you will get a dialogue like the following (under XP):

[image]

It's not fool-proof, but it stops the user from doing some basic things.

**Update**: Just realised that this also blocks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>, which I didn't realise before.

Comment: My application will be downloaded by students onto their own laptops, so I don't really want to mess with the registry.

Answer (score 6):

You can pre-run the hidden process taskmgr.exe

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "taskmgr.exe"));
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;

processTaskMgr = Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: I'm sure this idea came like an epiphany

Answer (score 4):

I achieved a similar goal, but with a different tactic in a Time Tracker tool I whipped up.  This will give you a form which takes over the screen - doesn't allow windows to appear on top of it and will shoot down task manager if it is started.

1. Set your form TopMost = True.
2. override the Form.OnLoad method like so:

   ```
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnLoad(e);
       this.Location = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Location;
       this.Size = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size;
   }
   ```
3. Create a timer, with a 500 millisecond interval, which looks for, and kills "taskmgr.exe" and "procexp.exe".
4. Override the Form.OnFormClosing:

   ```
   protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing || e.CloseReason == CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Nice try, but I don't think so...");
           e.Cancel = true;
           return;
       }
       base.OnFormClosing(e);
   }
   ```
5. Override OnSizeChanged:

   ```
   protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
       base.OnSizeChanged(e);
       this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
       this.Location = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Location;
       this.Size = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size;
       this.BringToFront();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. My code already contains everything you've said (Except the taskmanager killing). The computer could be on a domain in which case the taskmanager wouldn't even appear. Any idea on what I could do for that?

Comment: Why is that ability to open Windows Security a problem? All they can do their is "lock computer", "log off", "shut down", "change password" and open "task manager"(which this code prevents from functioning properly)...

Comment: This is the only solution so far which doesn't require admin privileges.

Comment: It's a working solution, but nothing stops a student that has renamed `taskmgr.exe` to `1337taskmgr.exe` and executes that before the app :) If this for computer science students, then the OP will have a hard time hardening his app either way.

Answer (score 2):

What do you really want to do ? [Disable the task manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555480) ?

```
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System 
Name: DisableTaskMgr
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 disable
```

But the user can still close your app with a third party task manager.

The proprietary application might "disable Ctrl+Alt+Del" using this registry key :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe, Debugger, Hotkey Disabled
```

Comment: "Image File Execution Options" is evil(well... not really). Good idea! The only drawback I can see is that if the application gets terminated in an unusual way than taskmgr will still be disabled (because the application won't have a chance to remove that key).

Comment: hmm... Your solution also has the same problem as mine... If the Welcome Screen is disabled than instead of taskmgr the Windows Security window opens when one presses Ctrl-Alt-Del. Which is not blocked by this.

Comment: I can't do any permanent changes such as changing the registry, because 1. I can't really assume that my program will have administrator privileges - actually admin privileges would be the exception. 2. If my program crashes for some reason, it'll be additional troubleshooting work for the college staff

Comment: The computer might also be part of a domain, so blocking the taskmanager alone will not help. Actually, blocking the taskmanger wouldn't be so much trouble - I could search for the Window Title n close it or follow some of the described Hackish methods.

Answer (score 2):

There're three ways of doing it (registry, administrative templates and hooks) described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc188951.aspx).

The code is in C++, but it will be easy to port it to C# with P/Invoke.

Comment: I've seen the page before. I've downloaded the sample, but even that doesn't work. All the other options except Control+Alt+Del work, but checking "Block Control+Alt+Del" option crashes the application. - I was running the already compiled Binary, so it wasn't a problem with compilation etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Windows Internal book (4th edition), Ctrl-Alt-Del sequence cannot be intercepted by non-privileged applications. Also, it is said that this particular sequence cannot be intercepted and that the Winlogon process will always receive it (page 529).

I never tried to do this, however, but I would trust the book :)

Comment: Won't trust it. Siemens Syngo (Medical images) block Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the other answers, there is no secure way of accomplishing this without checking each student's computers, because they could always run a VM.

As an alternative, have you considered burning your app to a LiveCD and requiring students to boot the LiveCD?

That way, you control their OS as long as they are running your app. Once done, they can reboot and everything's back to normal.

Of course, students could reboot their laptops inbetween, but that would probably take long enough to be noticed by the supervisors.

The VM solution would still trick this, so you'd need to make sure everyone really boots from the CD; otherwise I cannot think of any way around this.

As a bonus, you'll be isolated from any weird OS problems on the student's laptops (maybe some installed Linux or OS X ;-) ) .

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I have arrived at - as the only reasonably fool proof one. When I trying to block keys, most Antiviruses don't like it :(

Comment: live cd could be run in vm. http://serverfault.com/questions/163234/boot-a-linux-live-cd-in-vmware

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail: Yes, that is mentioned in my answer: "The VM solution would still trick this, so you'd need to make sure everyone really boots from the CD".

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

Make the app so you never need to use the alt or ctrl key.

Then, take out the Ctrl (or alt) key and put paper on the contacts.

Tada!

(just use another keyboard for maintenance)

Comment: Did you try it? 
I tried in my system before commenting this. Can't Ctrl-Alt-Del using the OSK or a combination of OSK and the actual keyboard.

Or is my system borked?

Comment: moogs, check out my "second" solution... It's a bit like yours :)

Answer (score 0):

A very dumb solution (which assumes that the machine is dedicated your software) is to **remap the Alt key** (*to nothing*).

Drawbacks:

- Permanent effect
- Requires a restart/logoff to activate

**Works on xp, Vista, W7.**

You can use [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to remap/disable any key.

[For info on what registry key SharpKey changes see this. One can also remap on a per user basis.](http://www.usnetizen.com/fix_capslock.php)

> **Warning**: If you disable the Alt key and
>   login requires you to press
>   Ctrl+Alt+Del than you won't be able to
>   login. :)

Comment: It's a bit like moogs' solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to block alt+F4 with something like this:

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4 && e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
        e.Handled = true;
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: You can also just set Cancel to true if CloseReason is CloseReason.UserClosing or CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing in the OnFormClosing event.

Comment: @Philip: awesome, I didn't know that would catch alt+F4 too. Thanks!

Comment: I already have a solution which blocks all the keys..except the almight Control+alt+del.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could install a filter on the keyboard driver?

I know on USB interfaces, you can install an upper or lower filter to the USB data to intercept it as it arrives on the computer, and perhaps a similar approach could be taken. Essentially, you would modify the key combinations coming from the keyboard as long as your testing application is running.

I did find an 'UpperFilters' registry key defined for my keyboard...

This [USB sniffer](http://benoit.papillault.free.fr/usbsnoop/doc.php.en) comes with source code that implement a filter. It may be usable in the context of a keyboard sniffer / modifying filter. ([Download link](http://benoit.papillault.free.fr/usbsnoop/))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest other way to disable Task Manager, works well with Windows 7 yet it just affects task manager option. The solution is to set following registry key to irrelevant value, like "C:\"

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe\Debugger
```

You can also use this hack to start your own task manager, just by setting Debugger key to full path of your application. I have discovered this by analysing how [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) replaces TaskMgr.