# Disable everything in windows except program c#

Tags: c#, windows, kiosk-mode

I've got the following question:

Is it possible te disable everything in windows except the program it's running?

I need to program an application on a touchscreen (fullscreen), where people can fill in a survey.
The only thing they should use is this program. (for protection of the survey anwsers and other secret stuff :p )
And the program should be closed when entering the right password.

So how can I disable everything else but the program I'm running?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block Control+Alt+Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660106/block-controlaltdelete)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should investigate [Kiosk Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software). It might not be the right solution for your particular case, but it is an accepted way of restricting users to one application.

[Kiosk Mode in IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)

Basically you make the application full screen and disable things like the task bar etc.:

> Disable the start menu and other stuff through the Group Policy Management
>   for the local computer (run gpedit.msc -> User Configuration ->
>   Administrative templates -> Start menu and Taskbar).

[Source](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/258834-kiosk-mode)

Answer (score 1):

[This KB entry describes how to do that the best way by replacing the shell.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555463)