# Disable Keyboard/Mouse in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to disable keyboard/mouse or both for specific time period at system level in my application.

I have following to do that

```
    public partial class NativeMethods
    {
        /// Return Type: BOOL->int
        ///fBlockIt: BOOL->int
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);

    }
```

By this code the task is complete but when user click on CTRL+ALT+DELETE keyboard and mouse are working again.
Can any body tell me how to stop this?

Comment: You can't stop CTRL+ALT+DEL from happening.

Comment: This may sound obvious, but if you're in a scenario that needs this, perhaps just unplugging the mouse and keyboard would be a better option. Unless of course you're writing a root-kit, in which case I doubt people will be so forth-coming in helping you.

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve by disabling the keyboard and mouse?

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660106/block-controlaltdelete) for some information

Comment: Need to do this when user enter a wrong key to pc, keybord or mouse or both are locked and when user removes that key then it is unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

Windows level shortcuts and macros (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ESC</kbd>) are messages that are not processed by your application, they're processed by windows runtime. You can check this by creating a simple form and overriding the `WndProc` method and checking those messages.
 Anyway here are some tutorials on how to hook the keyboard:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: Need to do this when user enter a wrong key to pc, keybord or mouse or both are locked and when user removes that key then it is unlocked

Comment: @HetalJariwala hummm well... im not sure if I followed you correctly but if the keyboard/mouse are blocked how do you gonna take input from the user to "remove that key"... anyway... check my edit...

Comment: By removing pendrive the keyboard and mouse are working again
And tnx for reply

Comment: @HetalJariwala dont forget to vote up or mark as answer if this solved your problem!

Comment: i don't have reptation more than 15

Comment: Downvote. This feels a bit too close to a link-only answer to me. What if those links died? I suggest explaining a bit in the answer itself, rather than just linking to other websites.