# Force login after pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del or prevent killing processes?

Tags: c#

I have an application that plays a video. While that video is running, the guy that started the video leaves the room. Now my program should prevent anyone messing with the computer while the trainer is away.

I successfully prevent Alt-F4, Alt-Tab and so on. **I also understand that I cannot prevent Ctrl-Alt-Del to be pressed** as this is a crucial system function.
But:

Can I make sure that after pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del the user cannot kill my application or switch to another application using the TaskManager?

(Being able to log off is fine)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block Control+Alt+Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660106/block-controlaltdelete)

Comment: If the system can be configured, you can enable the "Remove Task Manager" group policy, or make a limited user account and run the process as administrator (so the user will need to provide the administrator password to kill the process)

Comment: @aloisdg it is NOT a duplicate. As I already wrote "I also understand that I cannot prevent Ctrl-Alt-Del to be pressed"

Comment: if you don't want people to mess with it, then why is logging off allowed?

Comment: We are not talking about MS Video Screen saver?  Where the computer is already lock and the video is displayed

Comment: Consider to get ahead by not making the trainer's absence a special case, you can't get a reliable indication that they left the room.  Locking down a machine like that is a common need and done with OS config instead of code.  A decent google query to get ahead is "windows kiosk app".

Comment: As an out of the box suggestion: you could have a wireless keyboard and have the "guy that started the video" leave with the keyboard. Some further configuration tinkering might be required to prevent people from bringing their own keyboard, if that's *really* a concern -- ultimately you can only reliably prevent tampering by making the machine physically inaccessible, and if solving that problem essentially solves this one as well.